# Показать плавно меню по клику на элемент

Tags: html, jquery, css, click

p.s.Гифка с заданием http://yapx.ru/v/BTaYd . А ниже, мои попытки объяснить :) 
Нужно сделать плавный скролл + появление элемента с текстом + скрыть круг.
 Пока не сталкивался с такой задачей, не знаю как решить

[пример напишу и в codepen, и здесь](https://codepen.io/likeavenus/pen/MGmPOK)

```js
$('.wrap').click(function() {
  $('.hide-text').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: aqua;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hide-text {
  display: none;
}

.hide-text-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="wrap">Заголовок 1</div>
  <div class="wrap">Заголовок 2</div>
  <div class="wrap">Заголовок 3</div>
</div>
<div class="hide-text-wrap">
  <div class="hide-text">
    Заголовок 1 (замещение)
  </div>
  <div class="hide-text">
    Заголовок 2 (замещение)
  </div>
  <div class="hide-text">
    Заголовок 3 (замещение)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял честное слово

Comment: Согласен, плохо объяснил. Держите гифку, там все видно http://yapx.ru/v/BTaYd

Comment: На гифке я так понимаю просто плавный скролл к елементу?

Comment: Плавный скролл и появление элемента с текстом. + Круги становятся полностью прозрачными.

Comment: Пробовал через .animate, но походу не то